# Some troubles with compiler mingw_w64

Tags: c++, mingw, c++20, mingw-w64

Yesterday I started making some project and today I check out that my compiler (mingw_w64) is the newest one which I find in Internet (8.1) but I don't have all functions from C++20. So maybe someone know how to figure out this? If it somehow help my IDE is QT creator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61811384/compiler-to-c20-on-windows

Comment: Do you mean compiler g++?  v8.1 is certainly not the latest version available on mingw

Comment: Mingw-w64 appears to keep its own versioning scheme, per this site: http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/start I don't know if it's the version people are using these days; I just avoid minGW if I can.

Answer (score 1):

C++ ISO standards and compilers do not progress at the same pace or with the same priorities. Also, C++ standards are available (drafts) before they are complete or officially published: quite often, compilers partially support the draft specs. The good side of this is that there are tables telling you what feature of a given standard is supported by a given version of GCC. You can find such a table for GCC [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html).

Answer (score 1):

The current latest release of GCC is GCC 11 and C++20 support has been available since GCC 10.

Another compiler is LLVM/Clang, but I don't believe their C++20 support is on the same level as GCC yet, though I excpect it to catch up soon.

Get the latest MinGW-w64 GCC build from: http://winlibs.com/

Comment: Update: GCC 13 is out now. You can still get a Windows version from: http://winlibs.com/